# How can I use autoincrementing column value as default value for another not nullable column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Lets say that we have `UserModel` with following columns:

```
class UserModel(declarative_base(bind=engine)):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Is there a way to set `id` as default value for `nickname` without changing anything outside the model class?

I tried using `default=id` and `server_default=id`, but IntegrityError is always raised on `commit`.

Also, I know that there is no `id` until `commit` or `flush` is performed, but calling flush outside is not an option for me.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the whole class, your question is very vague without seeing the whole model class!

Comment: @Dalek Updated. But as far as I know there is nothing that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [hybrid_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property) for this. Here example:

```
class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    nickname_str = Column(String, unique=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def nickname(self):
        return self.nickname_str or str(self.id)

    @nickname.expression
    def nickname(self):
        return case(
            [(self.nickname_str != None, self.nickname_str)],
            else_=cast(self.id, String)
        ).label('nickname')

    @nickname.setter
    def nickname(self, value):
        self.nickname_str = value
```

Full example [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8364977/).

Comment: Looks pretty good, but I really wonder if there is a way to make `nickname` not nullable?

Comment: I updated answer. Just add `nullable=False, default=''` to nickname_str and change `self.nickname_str != None` to `self.nickname_str != ''`

Comment: Unfortunately, it inserts an empty string. IntegrityError is raised on 2nd commit (duplicate key violates unique constraint). Am I missing something?

Comment: Ops. I forgot that they are unique. Then it should be nullable.

Comment: There is no reason to make `nickname_str` not nullable because `nickname` would be always not null.